# Make a average from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this type of array and code in PHP:

```
$rooms = 6;

Array
(
    [2018-05-11] => 5
    [2018-05-12] => 5
)
```

`5` means I have `5` rooms occupied on `6` available.

So for the above example, I should get: 
`5/6*100 = 83.33`
`83.33*2/2 = 83.33`

I would like to make a average from these datas.

What I tried:

```
$average_percentage = round(array_sum($array*$rooms/100) / count($array), 2);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Why average dates

Comment: Maybe just fix the typos in $average_percentage : $average_percentage = round(array_sum($array)*$rooms/100 / count($array), 2);

Comment: @clearshot66: average dates? No I would like an average for the datas not the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arrayAvg = array_sum($array)/count($array);
$result = $arrayAvg * 100 / $rooms;
```

We can multiply outside array_sum because we use fact that

```
n*a + n*b + n*c + ....  = n * ( a + b + c +...)
```

- so we can first sum everything and then divide/multiply.

Comment: From my example, I should have `83.33`. I gave more information from my question.